# titlesec: \assignpagestyle problem with part

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

According to the `titlesec` documentation (section 3.5):

> You can assign a page style to levels of class top and page, as well
>   as the default chapter with the following command:
>   \assignpagestyle{command}{pagestyle}

It then states (section 3.9) that

> There are three classes: page is like the book \part, in a single
>   page, top is like \chapter ...

However using `\assignpagestyle` with `\part` doesn't seem to work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}  
\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}     % Doesn't work
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}  % Works

\begin{document}

\part{Bar}
\chapter{Foo}

\end{document}
```

I know I can change the `\part` and `\chapter` pagestyles doing the following in the preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
```

but since I'm using the `titlesec` package for my headers I wanted to simply use the `\assignpagestyle` command.

Comment: `\part` is usually defined in a non-standard way and it must be assigned somehow to the `page` class before making use of many features, including `\titlespacing` (with `\titleformat`, for example). The manual should make this point clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works once you define a format for `\part` (the reason for this is not clear to me, but in the past I've found that the behaviour for `\part` commands is rather singular when using `titlesec`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}  

\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}     % Works
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}  % Works
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname\ \thepart}{22pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\part{Bar}
\chapter{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solves the problem. So, basically, the command doesn't work the way the documentation suggests it should?

Comment: @petobens it works, but only if a `\titleformat` for `\part` has been used. I will write some note asking about this to Javier Bezos.