# Modify page layout using titleps

Tags: page-numbering, titleps

I defined 3 different page styles with `titleps`. I also used `titlesec` to define a new sectioning level namely `\subpart`.

Now I can't use this new level's title with titleps as header in odd pages. I don't know how to introduce it to `titleps`. I include the code I used, it delivers what I intend(apart from the above mentioned problem), but I'd really appreciate if you could refine it.

I marked the problem in the comment to the *main* page-style definition.

Note: Upon @cfr's remark I removed vide page-style definition.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[rm,small,center,compact,newparttoc,clearempty]{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subpart}{page}[\part]
%
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\thechapter .,. \chaptertitlename}
\newcounter{subpart}

\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\Alph{subpart}}
\newcommand{\subpartname}{Subpart}
%
\titleformat{\subpart}[display]{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
{\subpartname~\thesubpart}{1pc}{\Huge\bfseries}
%
\titlespacing{\subpart}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{subpart}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\normalfont\bfseries}%
{\thecontentslabel\enspace ---\enspace\large}%
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{2em plus 1fill}\large\contentspage}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{main}{
    \sethead[][\chaptertitle][] % even
    {}{\subparttitle}{} % Problem: Here I want to have subpart title. 
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]
    {}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{main}


\newpagestyle{preface}{
    \sethead[][\chaptertitle][] % even
    {}{\chaptertitle}{} % odd
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]
    {}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{preface}
\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}%it is a titlesec pkg command which suppresses page number only on the first page of the relevant sectioning command
\assignpagestyle{\subpart}{empty}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
.
.
.
\chapter[Preface]{PREFACE}
\pagestyle{preface}
.
.
.
\mainmatter
\part{History}
\subpart{Primitive Historians}
\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{The Formation of the Concept of History}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your page style doesn't seem to use the new division information at all, so it isn't clear what doesn't work. `vide` seems to be equivalent to `empty`, so a bit pointless, as far as I can see. `main` uses chapter, part and page information. `preface` uses chapter and page information. None of them try to use sub-part information.

Comment: I defined preface for the preface chapter only, because there is no higher level section above this chapter and using the main style would kept the odd pages of the preface without header. It was the solution which came to my mind in this simple manner and I searched for it and titleps provided this way of defining.

Comment: You need to not load `titleps` separately but as an option for `titlesec`, if you want them to work nicely together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `titleps` which titlemarks are defined using the `\settitlemarks` macro.  As cfr noted in the comments, you also need to load `titlesec` with the `pagestyles` option rather than loading the package separately.

So you need:

```
\usepackage[rm,small,center,compact,newparttoc,clearempty,pagestyles]{titlesec}
```

and then after you've made your new pagestyles:

```
\settitlemarks{part,subpart,chapter}
```

Here's a complete document. I haven't looked at the rest of your code. I've also added the `lipsum` package to show some pages.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[rm,small,center,compact,newparttoc,clearempty,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\titleclass{\subpart}{page}[\part]
%
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\thechapter .,. \chaptertitlename}
\newcounter{subpart}

\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\Alph{subpart}}
\newcommand{\subpartname}{Subpart}
%
\titleformat{\subpart}[display]{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
{\subpartname~\thesubpart}{1pc}{\Huge\bfseries}
%
\titlespacing{\subpart}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{subpart}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\normalfont\bfseries}%
{\thecontentslabel\enspace ---\enspace\large}%
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{2em plus 1fill}\large\contentspage}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\newpagestyle{main}{
    \sethead[][\chaptertitle][] % even
    {}{\subparttitle}{} % Problem: Here I want to have subpart title. 
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]
    {}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{main}


\newpagestyle{preface}{
    \sethead[][\chaptertitle][] % even
    {}{\chaptertitle}{} % odd
    \setfoot[][\thepage][]
    {}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}%it is a titlesec pkg command which suppresses page number only on the first page of the relevant sectioning command
\assignpagestyle{\subpart}{empty}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\settitlemarks{subpart,chapter}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
.
.
.
\chapter[Preface]{PREFACE}
\pagestyle{preface}
.
.
.
\part{History}
\subpart{Primitive Historians}
\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{The Formation of the Concept of History}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: correct headers]

Comment: Do you know why it is necessary to add `part` to the `\settitlemarks` and not just `subpart`? I just figured this out by trial-and-error but I'm clueless as to why it is needed when the default with only `chapter,section` obviously works fine.

Comment: I hope you don't mind Kant, but my answer used `kantlipsum` and I thought a screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for adding the screenshot. As for the inclusion of `part` that was an oversight [on my part :) ] For me, it *does* work with just `subpart, chapter`. Do you get an error or an incorrect output?

Comment: I got an error. It complained `\subparttitle` was not defined in that case. I thought it very strange that adding `part` resolved it.

Comment: @cfr Maybe you had an old `.aux` file? I just reran the posted code without the `part` in `\settitlemarks` and it compiles without error. I've also removed it from the answer.

Comment: I can't reproduce it now. I don't think I had an old `.aux`. I used `glanhau-tex` which definitely removes the `.aux`. (I realise this is not a ... er... commonly used command, but it does work.) I don't know what I did. Maybe I'm just confused. `titlesec` and friends tend to confuse me almost immediately, so this is a very likely hypothesis ;).

Comment: thank you both, I added the line you wrote and passing the pagestyles option to titlesec but it returned error and I have to go take an exam. I'll respond after my exam.

Comment: After an hour I finally recognized the source of the problem.In the front-matter I have a preface chapter and a acknowledgment as soon as I uncomment the latter it returns a bunch of error.

Comment: @AlanMunn  Even in your file the problem persists. ``\chapter{PREFACE}
\pagestyle{preface}
\kant[1-20]
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\kant[1-20]
``

Comment: @nima I can reproduce the problem but at the moment I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @AlanMunn I shall mention another problem here, the part page is numbered though I have the ``\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}``. By the way sorry I forgot to thank you for your answer.

Comment: @nima Yes, I've noticed that problem too.  For the original problem, if you put the `\settitlemarks{subpart,chapter}` *inside* the definition of the `{main}` pagestyle, the document will compile properly. I haven't updated the answer because I was hoping to solve the numbering problem too.

Comment: @AlanMunn In this question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117354)  the numbering problem is solved.