# Use Part title as header

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, titleps

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313080) I asked how to use the argument of a new sectioning level defined with the `titlesec` pkg as header. Now repeating the same code I'd like to ask how can I use the argument of `\part` command as header. It seemed easier, and I looked into `titlesec` documentation and there was a hint but I couldn't understand how to use it.

```
    \documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{titletoc}
    \usepackage[rm,small,center,compact,newparttoc,clearempty,pagestyles]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{kantlipsum}
    \titleclass{\subpart}{page}[\part]
    \newcounter{subpart}
    \renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\Alph{subpart}}
    \newcommand{\subpartname}{Subpart}
    \titleformat{\subpart}[display]{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
    {\subpartname~\thesubpart}{1pc}{\Huge\bfseries}
    \titlespacing{\subpart}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    \titlecontents{subpart}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\normalfont\bfseries}%
    {\thecontentslabel\enspace ---\enspace\large}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{2em plus 1fill}\large\contentspage}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

    \newpagestyle{main}{
        \sethead[][\chaptertitle][] 
        {}{\parttitle}{} % Problem: Here I want to have part title. 
        \setfoot[][\thepage][]
        {}{\thepage}{}}
    \pagestyle{main}


    \newpagestyle{preface}{
        \sethead[][\chaptertitle][]
        {}{\parttitle}{}
        \setfoot[][\thepage][]
        {}{\thepage}{}}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}
    \assignpagestyle{\subpart}{empty}
    \assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
    \settitlemarks{part,chapter}
    \begin{document}\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}

\chapter[Preface]{PREFACE}
\pagestyle{preface}
\kant[1-20]

\part{History}
\subpart{Primitive Historians}
\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{The Formation of the Concept of History}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I should've searched more and paid more attention than simply asking the question. By mixing parts of answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313080) and this one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117354), I could make  the `\part` argument as  the header, . First answer modifies the part style with the help of titlesec pkg,maybe facilitating the recognition  of this command by `titlesec` pkg and the second answer particularly his last comment on his answer made it possible to use it as header.

I used the minimal example of the second answer. Now the file has chapter title as header for even pages and part title as  header for odd pages.

Note: By modifying the `\part` the position of its argument slightly moves toward the top in comparison to the  original part command output, a fraction of a millimeter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}     % Works[removes the page number from the part page]
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}  % Works[removes the page number from the starting page of  the chapter]
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname\ \ \thepart}{22pt}{\Huge}

\newpagestyle{main}{
    \sethead[][\chaptertitle][] % even header
    {}{\parttitle}{} % odd header
    \setfoot[][\thepage][] % even footer: making the page number on th bottom of the page and center
    {}{\thepage}{} % odd footer
    \settitlemarks{part,chapter}}
\pagestyle{main}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \part{Bar}
        \chapter{Foo}
            \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just couldn't understand what are these two seperated backslashes in this line between ``\partname`` and ``\thepart``?  ``{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname\ \ \thepart}{22pt}{\Huge}``

Comment: `\ \ \thepart` just introduce two space characters before the part number. `\ ` stands for `space character`